# While installing npm live-server, I got an error

Tags: npm

Error:

```
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\live-server -> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\live-server\live-server.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\live-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ live-server@1.2.1
updated 1 package in 43.192s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error, this is a **warning**.

Your packages has been **installed successfully**.

The warning is about the `opn` dependency of `live-server` you can see it in the [official repository's `package.json`](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/blob/master/package.json) under the `dependencies` key. NPM simply states that this dependency has been renamed but `npm` took care of it.

An [issue](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/318) and a [pull request](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/pull/307) are open for this problem on the offical repository and the only one who can fix this is the maintainer of the repository.

Comment: Yes.But,even after using live-server command,I am not getting live page.What should maintainer of the repository should do to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by not getting live page ? You're page doesn't reload on file change ? That is not related with this problem.

Comment: I think he means that he can't launch live-server on his repository. @Scrap2312, did you install it globally, and not on a random subfolder on your computer?